# CudaMemcpyDeviceToHost failing with error code unspecified launch failure

Tags: c, cuda

I have a bool in the host which is copied to the device and then copied back to the host in a loop. This is my code.

```
bool h_done = true;
bool* d_done;

    while(h_done != false){

      err = cudaMemcpy(d_done, &h_done, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      ......
      bfs<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(h_edges, h_vertices, d_current_depth, d_done);
      err = cudaMemcpy(&h_done, d_done, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
     ......
     }
```

The code fails at the point where the bool has to be copied back from the device to the host with the following error.

```
Failed to copy d_done to host(error code unspecified launch failure)!
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: It isn't the cudamemcpy which is failing, it is your kernel launch. This is the same as you earlier question and I closed it as a duplicate of that

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are doing it elsewhere, but based on your provided code, you aren't doing:

```
d_done=(bool *)cudaMalloc(sizeof(bool))
```

Other great examples exist here:

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#device-memory

Comment: I've malloced memory on the device, that's not the issue.